# Why won't my toggle menu function work for a div (instead of a button) FIXED

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I originally wrote(/copied from w3) this javascript function that toggles a class called "show" to hide/reveal the menu. It was originally attached to a button, but I want to change it to a div. It works perfectly on the button, but when I call on the function from the div it doesn't work though. Any ideas? I used: `onclick="myFunction()"` for both in the html

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

EDIT
nvm I'm just dumb guys. I'm using an extension on vs code to get live updates and I just forgot to reset the connection-server thing smh I'm embarrassed of myself

Comment: Could you show additional JS or the HTML code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to add the eventListener to the "button"

```js
var myFunction = function () {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("show");
}
// you need to get the button from DOM
var myButton = document.querySelector('.call-me-a-button');
// then add the eventListener to the button saying what to do when the event occurs
myButton.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```css
#content {
    display: none;
}

#content.show {
    display: block;
}

.call-me-a-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"><h1>hello world</h1></div>
<div class="call-me-a-button">click me I'm a div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the div itself or mention any error message so it's hard to judge what's wrong, but here's a general example of how it would work:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.show
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

You can also use addEventListener to decouple the click handler from the markup - which is generally regarded as more maintainable and easier to follow:

```js
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.show
{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickme">Click me</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```